# Dynamically and asynchronously loading CSS (by setting the "href" attribute in Javascript)

Tags: javascript, css, performance, asynchronous, retina-display

On our site we load stylesheets dynamically based on whether the display is retina or not. Right now, we are using `document.write` for each `<link href="stylesheet.css">` we insert in the page, with different css files if the display is retina.

However, this hurts performance because it causes the css files to load synchronously, as the browser has no way of parsing the javascript to load the next file before the previous one is finished. I believe we can reduce page load time if we take advantage of modern browsers' capability to look ahead and fetch resources asynchronously - in another words, if we load the CSS files in parallel instead.

My current solution is to create a `<link id="link-tag-id" href="">` tag for every stylesheet to be loaded, immediately followed by a script which determines the retina status, then fills in the quotations with the appropriate file, along the lines of:

`document.getElementById("link-tag-id").setAttribute("href", "retina-stylesheet.css")`

This seems to work fine, and when I examine the network waterfalls in Chrome developer tools, as well as on WebPageTest.org  (running Chrome, Firefox, and IE), the stylesheets indeed load in parallel. However, it seems a little hacky. I was wondering if there are any dangers to creating a `<link>` tag with an empty `href` attribute, and if so, what are they?

On a broader note, are there any other recommendations on how to load CSS dynamically and asynchronously?

Thanks for your help!

EDIT: I just discovered this works too:

`document.getElementById("link-tag-id").href = "retina-stylesheet.css"`

Answer (score 0):

You could use media queries inside your stylesheet to determine if the display is a retina display, then load in the required CSS.

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/retina-display-media-query/

http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/

Comment: Thanks. Just tried this, with two separate <link> tags with media queries corresponding to retina and non-retina, but it looks like both still get downloaded. Is there any way to make it so that only the necessary stylesheet gets downloaded?

Comment: Combine the two stylesheets into one. Use media queries to change values that will be effected by the screen sizes, anything else can remain static.

Comment: While the question/answer are old, they are still relevant.  The issue here is not how many files are loaded, but how much data is transferred. By using media queries, you are effectively doubling the amount of data that is retrieved, which may have a seriously detrimental effect on the application.  For example, I have worked with a large application where fully optimised/minimised css was close to 1 MB in size (combination of multiple files).